# jQuery UI autocomplete, search 2 tables with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have 2 tables that need to be searched, I have listed the important tables and fields here:

```
Table: FAQs
Columns: id, title

Table: FIELD_VALUES
Columns: id, value
```

So basically the table FAQs holds a question 'title' and the table FIELD_VALUES holds information that can be related to the question in the table FAQs. So 'value' in this case is an answer in HTML format. What I need to do is search the table FAQs for the 'title', and search the table FIELD_VALUES for the 'value'. It should then only return unique question 'title' from the table FAQs.

I have gotten as far as returning the 'title' from FAQs using:

```
SELECT title FROM FAQs WHERE title LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'"
```

That works ok, but I am guessing I need to do some form of UNION and then a JOIN to return the title?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve...
what is the relation between these two tables? is it one to many (one faq with many values)? if so, then what is the name of the foreign key in FIELD_VALUES?

Comment: 1 'title' will only ever have 1 'value' related to it by the 'id'. In an ideal world I would change the db structure but I cant.

Comment: ok. So if I understood correctly both FAQ and Value always exist and have the same ids right? so what you need is not union, but join
try this:
select f.title, fv.value from FAQs f inner join FIELD_VALUES fv on f.id=fv.id where title LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'"

Comment: you might also want to read about SQL injections, because what you're doing here is pretty dangerous

Comment: Yes I will look at doing it all safely. I just wanted to get the correct way of doing it. I will give your suggestion a whirl as soon as I get a spare moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it as you want the title returned in all cases. Either if the search matches the title in FAQs, the value in the FIELD_VALUES or if both matches. Then you should do a join:

```
SELECT FAQs.title FROM FAQs
JOIN FIELD_VALUES ON FIELD_VALUES.id = FAQs.id
WHERE FAQs.title LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' OR
FIELD_VALUES.value LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'
```

Comment: You understand correctly, I am looking for the title to be returned in all cases. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a foreign key to your FIELD_VALUES table you should be able to achieve what you want:

`Table: FAQs`
`Columns: id, title`

`Table: FIELD_VALUES`
`Columns: id, faqId_FK, value`

Then your SQL would look like:

```
$title = SELECT * FROM FAQs WHERE title LIKE '%". $_REQUEST['term']."%';
if(empty($title)) {
  $valueId = SELECT faqId_FK FROM FIELD_VALUES WHERE value LIKE '%". $_REQUEST['term']."%';
  if(!empty($valueId)) {
    $title = SELECT title FROM FAQs WHERE id = $valueId;
  }
}  

echo $title
```

Without some kind of link between your tables it will be impossible to tell which values go with which titles.

Comment: I only want to return the 'title' in the dropdown. So if the search matches something in the 'title' that 'title' displays. If the search matches something in the 'value', the 'title' it is related to by 'id' is displayed. If the search matches both the 'title' and 'value', just the 'title' is displayed.

Comment: Got it, so a foreign key linking the value back to the title is still required.  Currently it looks like you have primary key id's on both tables but nothing linking them together.  You could use 2 queries with logic to achieve this.

Comment: Changing the DB structure is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Are they already linked? Is the FIELD_VALUES id = FAQs id?  If so I will change 'faqId_FK' to simply 'id' in the example query above. Also Niklas' answer should work as well.